# I can't turn my key on, in the start key.can you help pls

Tags: engine, starting

I can't turn my key on, in the start key.can you help pls
any idea?

Comment: Evelyn, we're going to need quite a bit more information in order to help. What type of car are we talking about? If it is turn-key ignition, does the key turn at all? If the key turns, does anything happen (sounds, lights, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

The key may be jammed due to the steering lock - apply pressure in either direction to the steering wheel to free the lock and then the key should turn.